# AngularJS website - Connection refused in Chrome and Firefox browsers

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio, iis, localhost

I have an `angularjs` website. I am using Visual Studio IDE.
The site runs good in **Internet Explorer**.
It shows error **"Connection Refused"** in **Chrome** and **Firefox**

I also have tested my `IIS` with hosting demo html page. Same issue with it. Seems problem with my `IIS` configs.
Code looks good. Can anyone help me with that?

[image: Screenshot in website in chrome]

Comment: "Code looks good" - where is the code? Any IIS configurations ? Update the question with these details please.

Comment: I have added simple html page with "<h1>hello world</h1>" in wwwroot folder. While trying to access it with localhost/filename/html, it is showing "Connection Refused" in chrome and ff. But running in IE. There seems nothing related to my code. I just have enabled IIS. All default configs in IIS. Any specific configs you want see? I can share screenshot

Comment: Solved. I had issue with proxy in my browser. By bypassing proxy for localhost working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is really incomplete information. You should have mentioned your chrome version, if other sites it loads or not, etc.

The first thing you should try is to update your chrome.

[This](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/KxxVHJpyemE) is the link of google forum. One of the answers from this should work for you.

Comment: Issue is not only with chrome. All browsers except IE creating issue. It seemed issue with my iis, not sure.

Chrome : Latest 61.0.3163.91
IE: 11.103.10586.0

Comment: see if [this](https://specopssoft.com/blog/configuring-chrome-and-firefox-for-windows-integrated-authentication/) works.